# Using Dapper to select data from MS SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dapper

I use Dapper to select data form Mssql, It result display "null"

(use stored procedure、 List to get data, and "myDictionary[0].Account" and myDictionary[0].Password to get detail information) ,

but MS SQL database have data.

How can I fix code ? thanks.

```
public void Do_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strAccount = Request.Form["userAccount"];
        string strPassword = Request.Form["userPwd"];

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                List<LoginModel> myDictionary = 
                    conn.Query<LoginModel>(@"uspSelectLoginChk",
                                            new { LoginAcc = strAccount, LoginPsd = strPassword }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
               string strAccountChk =  myDictionary[0].Account;
               string strPASChk =  myDictionary[0].Password;

                conn.Close();


                if (strAccountChk != null && strAccountChk != null)
                {

                    Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
                }
                else
                {

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               response.write( ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

```
// Modified your code
public void Do_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strAccount = Request.Form["userAccount"];
    string strPassword = Request.Form["userPwd"];
    var _para = new DynamicParameters();
    _para.Add("@LoginAcc", strAccount);
    _para.Add("@LoginPsd", strPassword);
    var _list = _con.Query<LoginModel>("uspSelectLoginChk", _para, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); // _con is SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")
    if(_list != null) {
        Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check:
 execute sp in sql with parameter which can view in debug the code.

```
   example:
   exec uspSelectLoginChk 'LoginAccValue', 'LoginPsdValue'
```

if a any data in sql execute,your code is error,if no data, you can insert data before with a data debug result.
Thanks